# What is difference between registering a dll to ISA server using regsvr32 and manually updating the system registry?

Tags: dll, isapi, regsvr32

I have scenario where I need to add a dll to ISA server. I have two options, either to use regsvr32 or manually update the system registry. I don't have much idea about how regsvr32 will register the dll. Please let me know what should be proper/cleaner way to register the dll.

TIA
Anil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like share the solution, the regsvr32 is cleaner way to register and unregister the filter to ISA server. We only need to have DllRegisterServer(void) function in our dll code.